# XSLT: replace all href based on text

Tags: xslt, kml

I need to replace the Iconstyle href in kml files. I'm having trouble getting the right xslt written for the following:

---

**Pseudocode:**

Select all href found in InconStyle
If href|text() = "y" then replace with "x"   (*where y and x are a list of mappings.*)

Then output the whole document again, with the changes.

---

XML block example:

```
<Style id='sn_x_normal0'>
    <IconStyle>
        <color>FFFFFFFF</color>
        <scale>0.75</scale>
        **<Icon><href>/ge/icon1.gif</href></Icon>**
        <hotSpot x='0.5' y='0' xunits='fraction' yunits='fraction'/>
    </IconStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>FFFFFFFF</color>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>FFFFFFFF</color>
    </PolyStyle>
    <ListStyle>
    </ListStyle>
</Style>
```

Expected output from the above xml:

```
<Style id='sn_x_normal0'>
    <IconStyle>
        <color>FFFFFFFF</color>
        <scale>0.75</scale>
        **<Icon><href>/ge/icon2.gif</href></Icon>**
        <hotSpot x='0.5' y='0' xunits='fraction' yunits='fraction'/>
    </IconStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>FFFFFFFF</color>
    </LineStyle>
    <PolyStyle>
        <color>FFFFFFFF</color>
    </PolyStyle>
    <ListStyle>
    </ListStyle>
</Style>
```

The xslt tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Icon">
    <xsl:variable name="newIcon">
      <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="href" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="icon1.gif" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="icon2.gif" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each  select="Icon/href">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please post your expected output and the tried XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Select all href found in InconStyle If href|text() = "y" then replace
>   with "x"

That's not exactly what your example shows us. It does *"If href|text() **contains** "y"..."*

Anyway, try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Icon/href">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'icon1.gif'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'icon2.gif'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the single quotes in:

```
<xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'icon1.gif'" />
<xsl:with-param name="by" select="'icon2.gif'" />
```

Without these, your template will look for nodes named `icon1.gif` and `icon2.gif`. In the absence of such nodes, the parameters will be empty and the template will go into an infinite loop.

---

P.S. To make this more efficient, change:

```
<xsl:template match="Icon/href">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="Icon/href[contains(., 'icon1.gif')]">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the delay in accepting, as I was away from the office. This has been a great help.